# Measure on function space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $F$ is a collection of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ (with the $\sup$ metric) and $\mu$ is a probability measure on $F$.  Is it true that the mapping $x \mapsto \int_F f(x) \, d\mu(f)$ is continuous?

Comment: There's no reason that integral should even exist.

Comment: Of course.  But suppose you know that the integral is finite for each $x$.  What then?

Comment: There's a lot you have to fill in here. What $\sigma$-algebra are you talking about, for example?

Comment: $F$ inherits the metric structure of $C[0,1]$.  You can take it to be closed if that helps.  So we take the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $F$.  This lets us define a probability measure on $F$ (or more precisely, on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $F$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying the integral is finite for each $x$ cannot be enough...

Say $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of disjoint open intervals tending to $0$. Say $f_n\ge0$, $f_n$ is supported in $I_n$, and $f_n(x_n)=3^n$ for some $x_n\in I_n$. Take $\mu$ supported on $\{f_n\}$ with $\mu(f_n))=2^{-n}$. Then the integral, let's call it $\phi(x)$, is finite for every $x$, but $\phi$ is not continuous, in particular $\phi(0)=0$ while $\phi(x_n)\to\infty$.

If you assume that $\int||f||\,d\mu(f)<\infty$ then $\phi$ is continuous, by dominated convergence.

Comment: Thanks.  This tells me I need some other assumption, and thanks for suggesting one.